# Firefox Video Play Errors on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: firefox, video, raspberrypi

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Raspberry Pi4 with 8GB RAM and Firefox 117.0.1 installed.
I'm seeing the following errors via journalctl -f, when starting to view an OReily course video on Firefox:

```
firefox_firefox.desktop[16910]: [GFX1-]: Couldn't sanitize RENDERER device: V3D 4.2

firefox_firefox.desktop[17042]: libva info: Trying to open /snap/firefox/3134/gnome-platform/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/v3d_drv_video.so
Sep 19 13:38:00 jon-rpi-ubuntu firefox_firefox.desktop[17042]: libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1

Sep 19 13:38:01 jon-rpi-ubuntu firefox_firefox.desktop[17620]: [Child 17620, MediaDecoderStateMachine #3] WARNING: Decoder=ffff8a67d900 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachineBase.cpp:166
```

Any ideas on what is causing these errors?

Thanks.